# Extend the Custom view pages in Razor View Engine and setting the themes dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I was using the following kind of code in my asp.net mvc2.

```
public class MyViewPage : ViewPage
{
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerSettingData csd = GetCustomerData(_customerId);

        this.Theme = viewMetaData.Theme;
    }
 }
```

In which i will find the theme based on the logged in customer and then render the theme. How can i accomplish this kind of thing in Razor Views. If i try to use this in Razor view it is giving error message.

> System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\59ad3d7b\f111dcde\App_Web_index.cshtml.e33b3359.tnkwzx_a.0.cs(79): error CS0115: 'ASP._Page_Areas_ERP_Views_Products_Index_cshtml.Execute()': no suitable method found to override at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath) at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine.FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, String virtualPath) at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]& searchedLocations) at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations) at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache) at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.<>c__DisplayClassc.<FindView>b__b(IViewEngine e) at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths) at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName) at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass1c.b*_19() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)

I am not able to understand this error message and fix the solution. If i use the 
`<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">`, i am not getting the exception, this exception occurs with the custom view page only.

Any suitable link or guidance is highly appreciated.

When i try like the following, i am notified that `this.Theme` is not available.

```
public class MyViewPageForRazorView : System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase
```

Comment: There is no such thing as Themes in Razor. This is classic ASP.NET WebForms artifact that shouldn't be used in an ASP.NET MVC application anyway.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Is there any way we can alteast mimic this kind of feature in Razor View engine. Atleast by having multiple `_Layout.cshtml` files for each theme and then choosing them for the theme.

Comment: Currently there's no theming support built-in WebMatrix. But you could always implement it of course.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I am not using `WebMatrix`. Hope you mis-spelt it. Do you have any suggestion for implementing one such. I can try it and post the status here.

Comment: You are using Razor, which is what WebMatrix uses. That's what I meant - Razor.

Comment: Yes You can do this in ASP.net mvc

Comment: @hajirazin: Can you please post on how it can be done.

Comment: Load the css file dynamicly using javascript